# Display a link clickable in a velocity template

Tags: velocity

In a velocity template I want to display a link which is in a variable. By now I just display the url, this line in my .vm template is :

```
URL : $topo.urlFileServer
```

How could I make it clickable?

Velocity version : 1.7

Comment: Use `<a>`tag like `<a href=$topo.urlFileServer>click here</a>`

Answer (score 4):

Velocity is just for rendering any text you provide to it *as-is*, it does not cares about what language you are using the Velocity Template engine to render. It could be HTML or any other language.

This problem is particularly related with HTML. You could use the data you have to make an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="$topo.urlFileServer">The Server's Link</a>
```

That would work.